# RAILS simpler way to pass an update form than create a new route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an order record that has multiple pipe/ funnel positions ( pipe_part ) each recorded by creation of a pipe_record that records who and when for that part.

I'm trying to create an update button that will post an edit to alter data in the pipe_record , so i iterate through the orders records then create a form for each position that already has a pipe_record then i want to either destroy or update , however I cant filter my recordset to make a form_for it returns a key issue

```
 <% @order.pipe.pipe_parts.order("priority").each do |part| %>
          <% if @pipe_records.where("pipe_part_id= ?",  part).present? %>
          <td>

                <% @pipe_position ||=part %>       
                <%= form_for @pipe_record.where("pipe_part_id= ?",  part)  do |f| %>
```

This throws a key error
undefined method `to_key' for # Did you mean? to_query to_ary

I created a second iteration of pipe_records in the controller incase was a cursor issue in the pipe_record recordset as below

```
   @pipes=Pipe.all.order("name")
   @pipe_records=@order.pipe_records
   @pipe_record=@order.pipe_records
```

I tried to make an obj in the second itteration with

```
<% if @pipe_records.where("pipe_part_id= ?",  part).present? do |pipe_record|%>
```

and then call

```
<%= form_for pipe_record do |f| %>
```

and am about to resort to creating a new route and controller for the update page as cant seem to get the id to pass to the @pipe_record but i know theres something obvious i've missed or structurally wrong in my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.first !

I forgot @pipe_record was a collection

```
<%= form_for @pipe_record.where("pipe_part_id= ?",  part).first  do |f| %>
```

Resolved